# Nuances of "once more" vs "once again" in the following sentence?

Tags: difference

To show the day is ending, I came across the following two sentences in a book I had read in a dream. I wonder if there are any nuanced differences between the two, and if so, what they are.

> "Once again the sun descended."
>
> "Once more the sun descended."

Comment: What was the dreamed author's name?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I don't remember if there even was a author name's on the book, much less what it was. Sorry to disappoint.

Answer (score 2):

*Once more X* can lean toward implying X is the last X.  *Once again X* does not.